# How to make this formula to work in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

How would one make this formula `=MAX(LEN(A2:A9))` work in Excel 2007?

I want the value of the longest field in `A2:A9` range.

I found this link: http://www.mrexcel.com/td0021.html, but it's old now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula looks right, but they way you are entering it is probably wrong.

You need to enter this as an `array formula`, type it in and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you have done it right, the formula in the formula looks like: `{=MAX(LEN(A2:A9))}`.

(Looked at your link - perhaps I should look at the links before answering in future - yes it's the same thing and still current.)

Comment: D'oh! That is even on the mrexcel.com site!